# Syntax Highlighting For Python Docstrings in Neovim Treesitter

Tags: python, python-3.x, neovim, treesitter

I'm using Treesitter with Neovim v0.8.2 and Python. With a default configuration of those 3, python  docstrings are highlighted as strings, and I'd like to highlight them as comments.

I've tried creating a ~/.config/nvim/after/syntax/python.vim file with

```
syn region Comment start=/"""/ end=/"""/
```

and I expected """<things here>""" to be highlighted as comments.

I'm guessing this is because treesitter is disabling syntax highlighting, so on that note has anyone been able to add custom highlighting rules to Treesitter or after it?

Comment: did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/4392

there's answer provided in that treesitter thread/issue. BTW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/4392

it's quite the read, but you can override how treesitter parses the objects in the document/buffer, can't take credit for the below solution, but should get you where you need to be.

```
after/queries/python/highlights.scm
```

```
 extends

; Module docstring
(module . (expression_statement (string) @comment))

; Class docstring
(class_definition
  body: (block . (expression_statement (string) @comment)))

; Function/method docstring
(function_definition
  body: (block . (expression_statement (string) @comment)))

; Attribute docstring
((expression_statement (assignment)) . (expression_statement (string) @comment))
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! That looks to contain the solution I’m looking for